# Как убрать эту подсказку?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда пишу System.out.print и ставлю скобки вылазит эта подсказка.
Подскажите, как убрать ее.

Comment: Это делается в настройках редактора."Настройки" → "Редактор", где-то тут, проверить не могу, нет редактора, но помнится, что это было в настройках редактора.

Answer (score 2):

Заходим в редактор нажимаем Ctrl+Alt+S. Затем Edito->General->Code Completion.
И под главой Parameter info убираем галочку с "Show parameter info popup in".

Answer (score 0):

Просто уведи курсор с параметров и таблица с параметрами пропадет

Comment: Я хочу чтобы оно вообще не появлялось

Comment: @zasik видимо эту таблицу нельзя отключить вообще.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь но я уже нашел как убрать

Comment: @zasik а как ее убрать? Стало самому интересно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/884513/310091